# What are "turning jets" and how to use them?

Tags: race-the-sun

In Race the Sun, I've finally unlocked the final ship mod, which is "Turning Jets" but I can't seem to tell if equipping them does anything. After copious button mashing, I'm somewhat befuddled.

Thusly, how does one use this item or if it's passive, what is it actually doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turning Jets - Increases your ship's reactivity when changing directions (Left <-> Right)